# HTTPS url for Community isn't redirecting

Tags: url, http, community-cloud

We are about to launch our Salesforce Community. We created a custom domain and URL using this option for our domain: "Salesforce serves the domain over HTTPS, on Salesforce's servers, using your HTTPS certificate." We uploaded a CA-signed certificate.

We've noticed that the behavior is different between HTTP and HTTPS when accessing the apex domain… `http://community.widen.com/` --> redirects okay to HTTPS and adds `/collective/s`

Accessing HTTPS apex `https://community.widen.com/` returns the broken redirect page that we were seeing before where the page HTML shows “/collective." Shouldn't Salesforce be returning a server-side redirect to `/collective` on **BOTH** HTTP and HTTPS?